# Meaning of passing from a column to a row vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When passing from column to row vectors in $K^n$ conceptually we're passing from a vector $(a_1,\ldots , a_n) \in K^n$ to it's associated linear functional defined by $ f(x_1,\ldots , x_n)=\sum_i a_i x_i.$

Now my question is: What does the inverse operation - passing from a row vector to a column vector in a coordinate space - conceptually mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that the map
$$\Phi: K^n \to (K^n)^*$$
you've defined by
$$\Phi(a_1, \ldots, a_n)(x_1, \ldots, x_n) := a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n$$
is not independent of the choice of basis of $K^n$; that is, if we pick a new basis of $K^n$, in general the map $\Phi$ changes.

Now we do have a canonical basis of $K^n$, namely the one whose $k$th element is the vector with $1$ in the $k$th slot and $0$ elsewhere, and provided we stick with this basis $\Phi$ is well-defined. We can, however, introduce a new object on $K^n$ that simultaneously gives an invariant (i.e., basis-independent) description of this operation and gives a conceptual description for changing between a row and a column vector.

Suppose $K$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and consider the standard inner product on $K^n$ defined by
$$\langle x, y \rangle := x_1 y_1 + \cdots + x_n y_n.$$
Then, for any $a \in K^n$, we have
$$\Phi(a)(x) = \langle a, x \rangle$$
for all $x \in K^n$, so we $\Phi$ (which sends a column vector to a row vector) sends $a$ to the map $K^n \to K$ that sends $x$ to its inner product with $a$. Using a basis it's easy to show that this map is bijective, so the inverse map simply maps such a "pairing" function $K^n \to K$ back to the vector $a \in K^n$ that defines it.

More generally, given an abstract (finite-dimensional) vector space $\mathbb{V}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ together with an inner product $\langle \, \cdot \, , \, \cdot \, \rangle$ on $\mathbb{V}$, we can define a map $\widetilde{\Phi}$ invariantly by
$$\widetilde{\Phi}(a)(x) := \langle a, x \rangle,$$
and by the above this coincides with $\Phi$ in the setting of $K^n$ endowed with the canonical basis and standard inner product. Note that in general this map is *not* simply writing the entries of a column vector as the entries of a row vector; this is only true in an orthogonal basis. In particular, the canonical basis on $K^n$ is orthogonal for the standard inner product defined above.

Applying such a map $\widetilde{\Phi}$ is a special case of what in the language of tensors is sometimes called *lowering an index* with the given inner product, and we sometimes denote $a^{\flat} := \widetilde{\Phi}(a)$; likewise, applying $\widetilde{\Phi}^{-1}$ is sometimes called *raising an index*, and we similarly denote $\alpha^{\sharp} := \widetilde{\Phi}^{-1}(\alpha)$.

Comment: One thing confuses me: At the beginning you say $\Phi$ is dependent of the basis. Then you change notation and write $\Phi$ as in $(\star)$, but then you say one can show it's independent of a basis. But only the notation has changed, which confuses me...

Comment: It'S also unclear to me, why a scalar product should even depend on a basis: It's just a function, defined without any mentioning of any basis. (Of course, on can show, that *if* one picks  *any orthogonal* basis, the scalar product can be calculated just like the dot product.) So $\Phi$ should a priori also be independent of a basis.

Comment: I've adjusted the notation so now the basis-dependent map in the original question is denoted by $\Phi$, and the basis-independent map (which coincides with $\Phi$ in the special case that the vector space is $K^n$, the basis is the canonical one, an we use the standard inner product) is denoted by $\widetilde{\Phi}$. Like you say, an inner product doesn't depend on a choice of basis; in fact, this guarantees that $\widetilde{\Phi}$ is independent of basis.